# Amplify publish causes AccessDenied error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

I deploy a simple web app to `S3` via `amplify publish`. The hosting has `Cloudfront` enabled (I selected the PROD environment in amplify while setting up hosting) and I'm working in the `eu-central-1` region. But whenever I try to access the `Cloudfront` URL, I receive an `AccessDenied` error.

I followed a tutorial at https://medium.com/quasar-framework/creating-a-quasar-framework-application-with-aws-amplify-services-part-1-4-9a795f38e16d an the only thing I did differently was the region (tutorial uses `us-east-1` while I use `eu-central-1`).

The config of S3 and Cloudfront was done by amplify and so should be working in theory:

**Cloudfront:**

- Origin Domain Name or Path: `quasar-demo-hosting-bucket-dev.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` (originally it was without the `eu-central-1`, but I added it manually after it didn't work).
- Origin ID: `hostingS3Bucket`
- Origin Type: `S3 Origin`

**S3 Bucket Policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "MyPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "APIReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ********"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::quasar-demo-hosting-bucket-dev/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Research showed me that `Cloudfront` can have temporary trouble to access `S3` buckets in other regions. But I manually added the region to the origin in `Cloudfront` AND I have waited for 24h. I still get the "access denied".

I suspect this has something to do with the `S3` bucket not being in the default `us-east-1` region and amplify not setting up `Cloudfront` correctly in that case.

How can I get amplify to set the `S3` bucket and `Cloudfront` up correctly so that I can access my website through the `Cloudfront` URL?

Comment: could you please share your configuration of S3 and Cloudfront distribution.

Comment: I added the information to the question @RajPaliwal. Everything was automatically configured that way via `amplify`. The only thing I changed (after it didn't work) was to add the `eu-central-1` part to the S3 path configured in Cloudfront.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the additional information.

your `S3` Bucket Policy looks Ok.

- Regarding `Origin Domain name or Path`, It is always `S3` bucket appears in the drop down so no need to update it with `region`
- However there is one setting missing in your `Cloudfront Origin`.
  you need to select `Restrict Bucket access` to `Yes`

  As per `AWS documentation`
  *If you want to require that users always access your Amazon S3 content using CloudFront URLs, not Amazon S3 URLs, click Yes. This is useful when you are using signed URLs or signed cookies to restrict access to your content. In the Help, see "Serving Private Content through CloudFront*
- Now create `new Identity` or `select Existing Identity`
- Click on Create button to save Origin.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. Now it works. So it seems to be a bug in amplify that they do not set `Restricted Bucket Access` – I will report it to them.

Comment: @morgler did you report it? do you have a link to their response? i'm suffering from the same problem.

Comment: @cyrf I did not report it. It seems to me that Amplify is still lightyears away from production use. They have been struggling with so many problems over the last 12 months that I decided to move away from Amplify. I now use serverless.com to set up my environments. I can only hope that Amplify will one day be production-ready.

Comment: @morgler I am not sure where you guys are with this error but 8 months later, I still face the same issue. Damn, amplify.

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya I'm actually giving Amplify another shot this fall and I definitely see progress in many areas. For hosting you can now choose an Amplify managed hosting, which takes care of S3 and CloudFront for you – no need to manually tweak missing settings anymore. Try `amplify update hosting` for an existing site.

Comment: @morgler Oh, many thanks for the inputs. I got it working just couple of hours ago infact.

Answer (score 10):

For those whom the first solution does not work, also make sure that the `javascript.config.DistributionDir` in your `project-config.json` file is configured correctly. That can also cause the AccessDenied error (as I just learned the hard way).

Amplify expects your app entrypoint (index.html) to be at the first level within the directory you have configured. So if you accept the amplify default config (`dist`) and are using a project that puts the built files at a deeper level in the hierarchy (`dist/<project name>` in the case of angular 8), then it manifests as a 403 AccessDenied error after publishing. This is true of both the amplify and s3 hosting options.

docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/manual-deploys.html (see the end)

Comment: So to solve the problem, edit `amplify/.config/project-config.json` and update it to: `"DistributionDir": "dist/<project_name>"`.

Answer (score 6):

While the answer by @raj-paliwal helped me tremendously solving my original problem, Amplify has since fixed the problem with a new option.

If you type `Amplify add hosting` (or `Amplify update hosting` for an existing site), Amplify gives you the option of `Hosting with Amplify Console`.

[image]

Choosing this will also create a hosting environment with S3 and CloudFront, but Amplify will manage everything for you. With this option I had no problems at all. It seems that this first option fixes the bug I encountered.

If you want to upgrade an existing site from manual CloudFront and S3 hosting to a `Hosting with Amplify Console`, you have to call `amplify update hosting` and select the new option.

Answer (score 0):

{
"Sid": "Allow-Public-Access-To-Bucket",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": "*",
"Action": "s3:GetObject",
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
]
}

SOLVED: add this to the bucket policy
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-website-cloudfront-error-403/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please detail the exactly policy, and what section of policy resolves the question.